# How to access a color in code behind which is defined in a xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

It try to change a ForeColor or Backcolor with a color which is defined in another seperated xaml file. If i use this:

```
_toolTip.ForeColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["Color_001"];
```

I will get a exception thrown at the start of the programm:
System.InvalidCastException: "Specified cast is not valid."

If i use this:

```
_toolTip.ForeColor = Resources["Color_001"] as Color;
```

It tells me that the class Color does not allow Null and cant be referenced with as-operater.

Is there a way i missed out?

Code in ColorBrush.xaml

```
<Color x:Key="Color_001">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
```

Code in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ColorBrush.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Code in App.xaml.cs

```
        private void DesignToolTip(string tooltipText)
    {
        _toolTip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
        _toolTip.OwnerDraw = true;
        _toolTip.UseAnimation = true;
        _toolTip.Draw += GetToolTipDraw;
        _toolTip.Popup += GetToolTipPopUp;
        _toolTip.ToolTipTitle = tooltipText;
        _toolTip.AutoPopDelay = 500;
        _toolTip.AutomaticDelay = 500;
        _toolTip.ForeColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["Color_001"];
        //_toolTip.ForeColor = Resources["Color_001"] as Color;
        //_toolTip.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFFFF");
        _toolTip.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF181818");
    }
```

Comment: Do a direct cast instead.

Comment: @Aybe i think you mean something like this: 
_toolTip.ForeColor = (Color)Resources["Color_001"];
but with this i get the  exception; 

System.InvalidCastException: "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: When you debug the code and examine the type of the object returned by the expression `Resources["Color_001"]`, what do you find? You _did_ spend some time actually _debugging_ this problem before posting your question here, right? Beyond that, if you want an answer here, you need to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Little snippets of pieces of code here and there don't suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're casting to the right Color class :

```
        //Yep, working
        System.Windows.Media.Color color1 = (System.Windows.Media.Color)Application.Current.Resources["Color_001"];

        //Works too
        System.Windows.Media.Color? color2 = Application.Current.Resources["Color_001"] as System.Windows.Media.Color?;

        //InvalidCastException
        System.Drawing.Color color3 = (System.Drawing.Color)Application.Current.Resources["Color_001"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Final solution with the help of [Roger Leblanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4183988/roger-leblanc):

```
System.Windows.Media.Color color_01 = (System.Windows.Media.Color)Application.Current.Resources["Color_001"];
_toolTip.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color_01.A, color_01.R, color_01.G, color_01.B);
```